# React native firebase duplicate chat messages

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

I'm developing a chat application using react native and firebase firestore db, I have almost implemented that part but stuck where I need to listen to changes in my `messages` collection and get the latest message for current `roomId`, but everytime the listener listens, it duplicates the last message. I think I may know the reason as I'm using 3 `useEffects`, 1st for initial room status checking like whether a room is created between current 2 users or not, 2nd for initially fetching all messages if the room exists between the two users, 3rd for realtime listener. Below is the relevant code:

```js
const [messages, setMessages] = useState([]);
const [roomId, setRoomId] = useState('');

useEffect(() => {
  // logic to setRoomId
  // ...
  if (item?.members?.includes(userDetails?.uid)) {
      setRoomId(item.roomId);
      return true;
  }
  // ...
}, []);

// fetch all messages initially
    useEffect(() => {
        if (roomId) {
            const q = query(
                collection(db, 'messages'),
                where('roomId', '==', roomId),
                orderBy('createdAt', 'asc'),
            );
            getDocs(q)
                .then(result => {
                    const messages = result.docs.map(doc => {
                        const data = doc.data();
                        return {
                            id: data?.id,
                            roomId: data?.roomId,
                            sentBy: data?.sentBy,
                            text: data?.text,
                            user: data?.user,
                            createdAt: data?.createdAt,
                        };
                    });
                    setMessages(messages);
                })
                .catch(error => console.log(error));
        }
    }, [roomId]);

    // realtime message listener
    useEffect(() => {
        const unsub = onSnapshot(
            query(
                collection(db, 'messages'),
                where('roomId', '==', roomId),
                orderBy('createdAt', 'asc'),
            ),
            snapshot => {
                if (snapshot.docs.length > 0) {
                    const lastMessage = snapshot.docs[snapshot.docs.length - 1];
                    const data = lastMessage.data();
                    const newMessage: MessageType = {
                        id: data?.id,
                        roomId: data?.roomId,
                        sentBy: data?.sentBy,
                        text: data?.text,
                        user: data?.user,
                        createdAt: data?.createdAt,
                    };
                    setMessages((prevMessages: MessageType[]) => [
                        ...prevMessages,
                        newMessage,
                    ]);
                }
            },
        );
        return () => unsub();
    }, [roomId]); // please read below --> COMMENT-1
```

`COMMENT-1`: if I don't provide `roomId` here as a dependency, it does not duplicates, but as `setRoomId` is async in nature, it doesn't re-render the ui and `roomId` is still '', so I have to add `roomId` as a dependency here in order to fire it so that `roomId` is not '', if I add this dependency, the duplication of last message happens. So can anyone help provide a better or an optimal solution to this problem?

**EDIT-1**

I could do this and it works but I don't think it would be an optimal solution because whenever a new message arrives, it will map through all the messages from the beginning and set in `setMessages` and just imagine someone has 100k to 1M messages...

```js
// realtime message listener
    useEffect(() => {
        const unsub = onSnapshot(
            query(
                collection(db, 'messages'),
                where('roomId', '==', roomId),
                orderBy('createdAt', 'asc'),
            ),
            snapshot => {
                if (snapshot.docs.length > 0) {
                    const _messages = snapshot.docs.map(doc => {
                        const data = doc.data();
                        return {
                            id: data?.id,
                            roomId: data?.roomId,
                            sentBy: data?.sentBy,
                            text: data?.text,
                            user: data?.user,
                            createdAt: data?.createdAt,
                        };
                    });
                    setMessages(_messages);
                }
            },
        );
        return () => unsub();
    }, [roomId]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your best option for this would be to filter or add a check to see if the message id exists in that 3rd useEffect like so,

```
 useEffect(() => {
        const unsub = onSnapshot(
            query(
                collection(db, 'messages'),
                where('roomId', '==', roomId),
                orderBy('createdAt', 'asc'),
            ),
            snapshot => {
                if (snapshot.docs.length > 0) {
                    const lastMessage = snapshot.docs[snapshot.docs.length - 1];
                    const data = lastMessage.data();
                    const newMessage: MessageType = {
                        id: data?.id,
                        roomId: data?.roomId,
                        sentBy: data?.sentBy,
                        text: data?.text,
                        user: data?.user,
                        createdAt: data?.createdAt,
                    };
                    if(!messages.find(mess => mess.id === newMessage.id)){
                        setMessages((prevMessages: MessageType[]) => [
                            ...prevMessages,
                            newMessage,
                        ]);
                    }

                }
            },
        );
        return () => unsub();
    }, [roomId]); // please read below --> COMMENT-1
```

Comment: Hi, it is still the same...

Comment: could you try moving the code from your 3rd useEffect to your first one, that way you don't need to wait on the state reset from the roomId